# HTML/CSS : Create a side border that is thin at top and thick at bottom (trying to avoid using border images)

Tags: html, css, border

I want to create a side panel with a right border that is almost 0px at the top but gradually increases to 5px at the bottom.

I am trying to avoid border images as I want to use least of external resources such as images.

How can I do that.
I tried to search a lot for this but couldnot find it. So if somebody can point me to a similar question , that is also helpful.

Below is the link:
http://s15.postimg.org/ftodd5qx3/SNAPSHOT.png?noCache=1435470821

If you notice, the left is a div with a beige color border on left panel at right(left to image) which is having variable length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a pseudo after element on a container div and then use borders on that after element to create a triangle.

```
.box::after{
    border-right: 300px solid transparent;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 300px solid #666666;
}
```

See example here https://jsfiddle.net/vkkze6v0/